# Necessary to have Node.js with Angular for ui-select

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, node.js, jakarta-ee

I am trying to learn AngularJS. I have already built a simple web-app using AngularJS but having Java EE on the backend (server side). The web app is hosted on tomcat. I could clearly understand the convenience of AngularJS over JQuery.

On another JQuery web-app with JavaEE on the backend, I used select2 (https://select2.org/). When changing to AngularJS with JavaEE in the backend, I realized, in order to use https://angular-ui.github.io/ui-select/ , I must have a Node application instead of a JavaEE backend.

Are there other ways to incorporate Select2 in AngularJS + JavaEE web application or do I need to learn Node.js to be able to develop meaningful apps in AngularJS?

Thanks,

Comment: You don't need `nodejs` to use `ui-select` as it is not listed in its dependencies. [Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/ZjU9i9TEqySC0jwkvAsD?p=preview).

Comment: Yes, you are right. It does not require nodejs, I can just include it using a cdn.

Answer (score -1):

You only need:

1. angularjs
2. Angular-Sanitize

Don't forget to inject ngSanitize into your module.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I included these using a CDN. Thanks. +1